Dimension of Jacobian Algebra (in Singularity Theory)
Motivation: In Singularity Theory, the Milnor Number is defined to be the dimension of the Jacobian algebra and is finite in the case of an isolated singularity.
We define the Jacobian algebra of a holomorphic function $f$ to be
$$\frac{\mathbb{C}\{z_0, \dots, z_n\}}{\langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial z_0}, \dots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial z_0}\rangle}, $$
where $\mathbb{C}\{z_0, \dots, z_n\}$ is the ring of convergent power series. The complex dimension as a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra of this is known to be finite in the case that the singular point of $f$ is isolated.
In order to understand this, I reason:

$\mathbb{C}$ is a field, and thus Noetherian. This implies $\mathbb{C}\{z_0, \dots, z_n\}$ is Noetherian and so the Jacobian algebra (as a quotient of a Noetherian ring) is Noetherian.

The Jacobian algebra has Krull dimension $0$, so we know that the Jacobian Algebra is Artinian, and thus finitely generated as a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra.


But this doesn't make use of any properties of the singular set of $f$, so I'm unsure why this Jacobian algebra is finite for the isolated singularity case and maybe not for non-isolated singularities.
Questions:

Is my reasoning for the finiteness of the algebra as a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ accurate?
What changes, if anything, between the cases of an isolated vs non-isolated singularity?


The missing bit here is the following: the singularity being isolated gives that the Jacobian algebra's Krull dimension is zero, and this is in fact an equivalence. The key idea in proving this is that prime ideals of this ring correspond to germs of subvarieties contained in the singular set also passing through the origin - the only such prime is $(z_0,\cdots,z_n)$ iff the singularity is isolated.
Past that, your reasoning is fine (except you want to say that the Jacobian algebra being Artinian implies that it is finitely generated as a $\Bbb C$-module instead of as a $\Bbb C$-algebra).
To see how things change when the singularity is not isolated, we can look at an example. Let's consider $V(z_0^2-z_1^3)$ as a subvariety in $\Bbb C^2$ and in $\Bbb C^3$. In the first case, the Jacobian algebra is $\Bbb C\{z_0,z_1\}/(z_0^2-z_1^3,2z_0,-3z_1)\cong \Bbb C$, while in the second case, the Jacobian algebra is $\Bbb C\{z_0,z_1,z_2\}/(z_0^2-z_1^3,2z_0,-3z_1) \cong \Bbb C\{z_2\}$, which has prime ideals $(0)\subset (z_2)$ and is therefore not zero-dimensional as a ring, not Artinian, nor finite-dimensional as a $\Bbb C$-module.

Thanks, that pretty much answers it.
